# Diferença na aplicação de font-weight bold/bolder

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber a diferença no uso das propriedades CSS **font-weight:bold** e **font-weight:bolder**, pois aplicando estas propriedades não consigo ver diferença entre uma e outra assim como font-weight normal e lighter. Será que seria alguma coisa relacionada a cross-browser?

```css
#teste1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#teste2 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#teste3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
#teste4 {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<p id="teste1">Testando!</p>
<p id="teste2">Testando!</p>
<p id="teste3">Testando!</p>
<p id="teste4">Testando!</p>
```

Comment: Tem uma pergunta igual a sua com boas respostas nesse link no StackOverflow inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592868/css-what-is-the-difference-between-bolder-and-bold-font-weight-styles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Bolder`, ou `lighter` na verdade é um atributo herdado. Vou explicar melhor. Se o pai tem `font` *normal*, e vc coloca `bolder` em um filho o browser entende que esse filho deve ter um negrito superior ao do pai. Assim como o `lighter` o browser entender que o filho deveria ter a fonte mais "leve" que a do pai.

Outro ponto a ter e mente é a limitação da própria `font-family` que muita vezes não tem um `font-wight` mais pesado que o próprio `bold`, então usar `bolder` seria a mesma coisa que `bold`, pois ela não tem um tipo mais pesado para aplicar, o mesmo acontece com o `lighter`, se a `font-family` não tiver um tipo mais leve o mais leve será o normal.

> The problem here is that the font itself must have one or more weights. If it has none you cannot make it bold at all.

PORTUGUÊS
*"O problema aqui é que a própria fonte deve ter um ou mais pesos. Se não tiver nenhuma, você não poderá negrito de forma alguma."*

Veja esse estudo de caso:

Para o caso de teste, foi usada a `font-family` **Segoe UI** para Windows. Se a fonte não tiver o peso para todos as configurações, por exemplo se ela não tiver até o 900 o máximo que ela vai chegar é no 700.

**OBS:** Fonte normal é considerado 400, acima disso *semi-bold*, *bold*, *extra bold*, `black` e abaixo *light*, *extra light*, *thin*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Fonte:* https://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/fontweight.html

---

**Tabla de referência da Mozilla:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Significado_de_pesos_relativos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: +1 Foi mais rápido que eu :)  [Esse link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Meaning_of_relative_weights) pode ser útil para saber o valor exato de `bolder` e `lighter` para cada `font-weight` do elemento pai.

Comment: @fernandosavio olha a imagem que acabei de incluir no Edit que fiz :D, pensamos juntos. Dessa vez foi maus rápido na resposta rss

Comment: Valeu Hugo, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Se o tipo de fonte usada tiver escalas disponíveis, o `bolder` irá assumir a próxima escala superior em referência à escala do elemento pai. O valor de `bold` usa a escala `700`, logo se o tipo de fonte usada tiver as escalas `800` ou `900`, o `bolder` irá assumir um desses valores, o que for imediatamente posterior a `700`.

Neste exemplo, usando uma fonte do [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Noto%20Serif%20TC:400,700,900), com escalas `700` e `900`, o `bolder` da div filho assume o valor de `900` em relação ao bold 700 da div pai:

```css
body{
   font-family: 'Noto Serif TC', serif;
}
#pai {
   font-weight: bold;
}
#filho {
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif+TC:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="pai">
   pai - 700 (negrito normal)
   <div id="filho">
      filho - 900 (negrito mais forte)
   </div>
</div>
```

> Creio não ter relação a cross-browser, mas sim ao tipo de fonte usada.

Comment: Muito bom exemplo Sam. Obrigado!

Comment: Bom exemplo mesmo, ficou bem didático